# cordovaHTTP is not defined

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm working with an HTTP request.

I have used this plugin:

https://github.com/panta/cordova-HTTP

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','ngCordova','ja.qr','ngStorage','ngCordovaHTTP'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform,$rootScope,$localStorage) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)

    console.log(cordovaHTTP);
```

But it throws an error:

> cordovaHTTP is undefined

In index.html

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova-http.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: define cordovaHTTP in .run() as **.run(function($ionicPlatform,$rootScope,$localStorage, cordovaHTTP) {** .

Comment: i use like that.it throw this error : **I/chromium(25561): [INFO:CONSOLE(17946)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cordovaHTTP' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js (17946)**

Answer (score 0):

cordovaHTTP is not the right naming for plugin clobber, "CordovaHttpPlugin" is the right one and is defined in window object.